# creating conda venv: conda env create VS conda env update

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When creating conda virtual environment with YAML file for the **first time**, I unknowingly ran:

```
conda env update -f environment.yml
call activate process_name
```

which successfully created a venv in: *C:\Users\userName\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs*.

Should I have ran the following instead?

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
call activate process_name
```

Does `conda env update` create a new venv if no existing venv is found in the anaconda envs directory?

How stable is `conda env update` in defaulting to creating a new venv if no existing venv is found?

Answer (score 0):

Both should work to create the new venv if such an environment doesn't exists. You can easily try this with a sample environment.yml

Create the following environment.yml file in a directory of your choice:

```
name: testenv123
dependencies:
  - python
  - pytorch
```

and then run this:

```
conda env update
activate testenv123
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does `conda env update` create a new venv if no existing venv is found
> in the anaconda envs directory?

Yes

> How stable is conda env update in defaulting to creating a new venv if
> no existing venv is found?

I could not find any documentation stating that it will create a new environment if the environment does not already exist.  Therefore I think that there are no guarantees about this behavior staying the same in the future.